# New to programming pong game paddle collisions in pygame?

Tags: pygame

Hi I am extremely new to coding in general and have been trying to improve my fluency. Thats why I started coding a pong game with Pygame because I wanted something visual. so I have created a pong design with working paddles and a ball that I have bouncing off walls but am having trouble getting the paddle collisions corect. I have it so it prints Paddle when my paddle and ball are aligned but it doesnt always detect it. How can I make it have more sensitivity and add bounce to the paddle. Once again I am very new so any syntax correction or advice on making the code easier to read or simplified would be great: the code is as follows :

```
import sys, pygame, pygame.mixer, random, math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_size = width, height = 600, 400
black = 0,0,0
red = (200,0,0)
blue = 0,0,200

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("PONG WANNABE")
screen.fill(black)

paddle = pygame.image.load("paddle.png")
divider = pygame.image.load("divider.png")


def addVectors((angle1, length1), (angle2, length2)):
    x = math.sin(angle1) * length1 + math.sin(angle2) * length2
    y = math.cos(angle1) * length1 + math.cos(angle2) * length2
    length = math.hypot(x, y)
    angle = 0.5 * math.pi - math.atan2(y, x)
    return (angle, length)


class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 8
        self.x = width/2
        self.y = height/2
        self.colour = (255, 255, 255)
        self.thickness = 0
        self.speed = 0.05
        self.angle = math.pi/2

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,self.colour,int(self.x),int(self.y)),
        self.size,self.thickness)

    def move(self):
        self.x += math.sin(self.angle) * self.speed
        self.y -= math.cos(self.angle) * self.speed

    def bounce(self):
        if self.x > width - self.size:
            self.x = 2*(width - self.size) - self.x
            self.angle = - self.angle
        elif self.x < self.size:
            self.x = 2*self.size - self.x
            self.angle = - self.angle
        if self.y > height - self.size:
            self.y = 2*(height - self.size) - self.y
            self.angle = math.pi - self.angle
        elif self.y < self.size:
            self.y = 2*self.size - self.y
            self.angle = math.pi - self.angle

ball = Ball()

running = True       
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
            black = blue
        elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_SPACE:
            black = 0,0,0
    screen.fill(black)
    mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.blit(divider,(width/2, 0))
    screen.blit(paddle,(10,my-35))
    screen.blit(paddle,(width-20,365-my))      
    ball.move()
    if ball.x < my + 73 and ball.x > my:
        print "Paddle"
    ball.bounce()
    ball.display()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly try to use Rectangles and check if the Rectangles collide. Full  documentation can be found at http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html but I'll still explain directly how in your case.

In your `Ball` class you will probably want to create a Rect.

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        #all of your x, y etc.
        #add in a react at the end of init
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.size, self.size)
        #self.size is the width and height
```

Then at the end of the function `move` you need to update the rect

```
def move(self):
    #move ball with what you already have
    #now update the rect
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
```

Now you'll want to create a rectangle for the paddle, now I dont know how wide your paddle is, but I'm going to just say 10 and you can adjust that as necessary.

So now to add the rectangle. In the while loop right after you get the x and y of the paddle add this line to create a rectangle
    mrect = pygame.Rect(mx, my, 10, 73)
So now you have a rectangle to work with to check for a collide point. Now instead of this line `if ball.x < my + 73 and ball.x > my:`  you need to change this to check for a collide point between your two rectangles. We're going to do this by using a function that is part of the class `pygame.Rect` called `colliderect`
So change the line `if ball.x < my + 73 and ball.x > my:` to this `if ball.rect.colliderect(mrect):` this will check if the rectangles, the ball or the paddle collide at any point.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**This is for double ball pong. name ball instances circle_m and circle_mc. name paddle instances rectangle and rectangle_mc. name boundaries boundary1 and boundary. name goals goal1 and goal2. name text boxes textField_1,textField_2, and textField_3. Then use this code and have fun.  (must be made in adobe flash obviously)**

```
//1.
var xDir2 = 1;
var yDir2 = 1;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, circleHit);
var xDir = 1;
var yDir = 1;
var score = 0;
var score2 = 0;
//2.
function circleHit(event:Event):void
{

{
    circle_mc.x +=  10 * xDir;
    circle_mc.y +=  10 * yDir;
    circle_m.x +=  5 * xDir2;
    circle_m.y +=  5 * yDir2;
    if (circle_mc.hitTestObject(rectangle_mc))
    {

        xDir *=  -1;
    }
};
if (circle_mc.hitTestObject(rectangle))
{
    xDir *=  -1;
}
if (circle_mc.hitTestObject(boundary))
{
    yDir *=  -1;
}
if (circle_mc.hitTestObject(boundary1))
{
    yDir *=  -1;
}
if (circle_mc.hitTestObject(goal2))
{
    score2++;
    circle_mc.y = 161.95;
    circle_mc.x = 273;

}
textField_2.text = score2;
textField_1.text = score;
if (circle_mc.hitTestObject(goal1))
{
    score++;
    circle_mc.y = 161.95;
    circle_mc.x = 273;
}


if (circle_m.hitTestObject(goal2))
{
    score2++;
    circle_m.x = 273;
    circle_m.y = 161.95;
}

if (circle_m.hitTestObject(goal1))
{
    score++;
    circle_m.x = 273;
    circle_m.y = 161.95;
}
if (circle_m.hitTestObject(rectangle_mc))
{   
    xDir2 *=  -1;
}
if (circle_m.hitTestObject(rectangle))
{
    hSiz2 *=  -2;
    xDir2 *=  -1;
}
if (circle_m.hitTestObject(boundary))
{
    yDir2 *=  -1;
}
if (circle_m.hitTestObject(boundary1))
{
    yDir2 *=  -1;
}
}
//This section creates variables to store the condition of each key A(up or down)
var keyUP:Boolean = false;
var keyDOWN:Boolean = false;
var keyRIGHT:Boolean = false;
var keyLEFT:Boolean = false;
```

This section creates event listeners. The first two check if any key has been pressed down or come back up. The third event listener controls a repeating loop

```
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,key_Up);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,key_Down);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
```

These functions changes the value of the variables if the key comes up.The switch statement; checks for which key is being processed. The case statements provide the options for each key with the number representing a key. break ends the case.

```
function key_Up(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
switch (event.keyCode)
{
    case Keyboard.W :
        keyLEFT = false;
        break;
    case 38 :
        keyUP = false;
        break;
    case Keyboard.S :
        keyRIGHT = false;
        break;
    case 40 :
        keyDOWN = false;
}
}
function key_Down(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
switch (event.keyCode)
{
    case Keyboard.W :
        keyLEFT = true;
        break;
    case 38 :
        keyUP = true;
        break;
    case Keyboard.S :
        keyRIGHT = true;
        break;
    case 40 :
        keyDOWN = true;
}
}
```

This function will repeat every time a frame is entered. It uses the values of the variables to control actions. The trace statement will display a word in the output window

```
function loop(event:Event)
{
if (keyUP)
{
    rectangle_mc.y -=  20;
}

if (keyDOWN)
{
    rectangle_mc.y -=  -20;
}

if (keyLEFT)
{
    rectangle.y -=  20;
}

if (keyRIGHT)
{
    rectangle.y -=  -20;
}

if (score ==10)
{
    textField_3.text = "Left side WINS!!!!!";
    circle_mc.y = -5000;
    circle_mc.x = -5000;
}
if (score2 ==10)
{
    textField_3.text = "Right side WINS!!!!!";
    circle_mc.y = -5000;
    circle_mc.x = -5000;
}
if (score ==10)
{
    textField_3.text = "Left side WINS!!!!!";
    circle_m.y = -5000;
    circle_m.x = -5000;
}
if (score2 ==10)
{
    textField_3.text = "Right side WINS!!!!!";
    circle_m.y = -5000;
    circle_m.x = -5000;
}
```

}